# Targeting the ahref by clicking the padding

Tags: css, navigation, click, whitespace

Newbie question here.  I have a navigation bar with padding in all of my li's, and I want to be able to target the ahref when you click in the padding.  Would this be done with onclick/javascript for each li?  or is there a simple CSS method?

Also I have a search bar, that I want to focus by clicking on it's padding as well.  I assume this would require a similar method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must set `display:inline-block` as a property for your links. Then, remove the padding from your list-item and apply it to the links.

Your CSS should reflect the following:

```
li a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px; 
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTFGL/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding to the anchor instead of to the `li`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/FBsKH/ and compare.

About the search bar, can you post some code?

If I add padding to a `<input type="text" />` and I click it on it's padding, it gets focus (tested on Firefox and Chrome). See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsRu/

**Edit:**

Ah, now I understand what you want with the search bar.

The problem is that AFAIK with CSS you can't set focus to an element.

Then, you can:

- Remove paddings: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsRu/3/
- Use JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsRu/4/

Comment: Great. That worked.  Thanks Oriol and also Vinny.    What about if I wanted to click in the area surrounding a search bar?  You couldn't apply padding the same way because the padding effects the search bar size.

Comment: I'm using chrome on windows and I see a huge text box instead of a regular size text box with padding.

Comment: this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsRu/2/   Ignore the mismatch in my alignments.  I'm mainly interested in clicking AROUND the search bar to target the search bar.  It is in the last bit of code.

Comment: @user1620806 Sorry I didn't understand what you wanted, see my edited post with search bar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could specify:

```
li.someclass a {
    display: inline-block; //or display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

(remember to specify width/height of parent container aswell)

not sure if i got you right though